# How to call the mutator methods in an overloaded constructor instead of assigning them in java?

Tags: java, bluej, mutators

```
 public class Player
{
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int heightInInches;
private double weightInPounds;
private boolean goalScorer;
private boolean drinksBeer;

public Player(){
}

public Player(String firstName, String lastName, int heightInInches, double weightInPounds, boolean goalScorer, boolean drinksBeer){
    if(lastName != null && lastName.trim().length() > 0){
        if(lastName != null && lastName.trim().length() > 0){
            if(heightInInches >= 0){ 
                if(weightInPounds >= 0){
                    this.firstName = firstName;
                    this.lastName = lastName;
                    this.heightInInches = heightInInches;
                    this.weightInPounds = weightInPounds;
                    this.goalScorer = goalScorer;
                    this.drinksBeer = drinksBeer;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName(){
    return lastName;
}

public int getHeightInInches(){
    return heightInInches;
}

public double getWeightInPounds(){
    return weightInPounds;
}

public boolean getGoalScorer(){
    return goalScorer;
}

public boolean getDrinksBeer(){
    return drinksBeer;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName){
    if(firstName != null && firstName.trim().length() > 0){
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Error. Invalid First Name.");
    }

}

public void setLastName(String lastName){
    if(lastName != null && lastName.trim().length() > 0){
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Error. Invalid Last Name.");
    }

}

public void setHeightInInches(int heightInInches){
    if(heightInInches >= 0){
        this.heightInInches = heightInInches;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Error. Invalid Height.");
    }

}

public void setWeightInPounds(double weightInPounds){
    if(weightInPounds >= 0){
        this.weightInPounds = weightInPounds;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Error. Invalid Weight.");
    }

}

public void setGoalScorer(boolean goalScorer){
    this.goalScorer = goalScorer;
}

public void setDrinksBeer(boolean drinksBeer){
    this.drinksBeer = drinksBeer;
}


}
```

In the overloaded constructor, how can I call the mutator method for each field instead of using an assignment statement? and also if I call the mutator methods should I remove the if statements in the constructor?
 (I'm using the blueJ)
I'm a beginner, so please mention if there is any other problems in my code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't call overridable methods in the constructor, since you expose half-constructed objects if this class is inherited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is reference the mutator method like any other method:

```
public Player(String firstName, String lastName, int heightInInches, double weightInPounds, boolean goalScorer, boolean drinksBeer) {
    setFirstName(firstName);
    setLastName(lastName);
    setHeightInInches(heightInInches);
    setWeightInPounds(weightInPounds);
    setGoalScorer(goalScorer);
    setDrinksBeer(drinksBeer);
}
```

Also, there's no need for those if statements, because they weren't actually doing anything useful.  If you don't explicitly set any values, `int` variables will default to `0`, `double` will default to `0.0`, `boolean` will default to `false`, and `String` will default to `null`.  So your if statements were doing things like "If the first name is `null`, don't set it . . . so it'll just be `null` anyway by default."

If you want to do something like forcing the height to be a positive number, you can always put that logic in the setter.

Comment: Note that it is strongly discouraged that one uses overridable method calls in the constructor. If the class is overridden, then an incomplete object state is exposed.